# Identify movie about a mother and daughter trapped in their home due to a break in

Tags: identify-this-movie

Sometime in high school, I stumbled upon a movie on a hotel tv while flipping channels.  I would have come across this movie around the 2009-2011 time period.  I only saw one chunk of the movie, as I came across it while it was already on, but I will do my best to describe exactly what I remember.

The movie was in English and looked to be modern.  The scene I saw had a woman and her daughter locked inside a house of some kind, possibly an apartment building.  They were hidden in what I thought was an elevator inside the home, hiding from two men who broke into their house.  If it wasn't an elevator, it had to be some kind of security system, having some sort of hide out in their house if they ever needed to be unseen and untouchable.  The daughter was diabetic, and the woman was trying to reason with the assailants to let her leave this locked and sealed room to go fetch her daughter's insulin kit that was somewhere else in the house.

Other details that are less vivid in my mind from this movie include the woman using some sort of satellite phone to call her husband, so he must have been at work or out of the country.  The family seemed rich and/or important.  The movie was real life, not animated.  They also kept showing outside for dramatic effect and it was dark, dreary, and very rainy the entire time.

If anyone can hunt this movie down, that would be great... I've been trying off and on to find the name of it to go back and see how it ends.  The movie was very intense and did a good job grabbing my interest.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Sounds like David Fincher's Panic Room from 2002 with Jodie Foster and Kristen Stewart.

> **A divorced woman and her diabetic daughter** take refuge in their newly-purchased house's safe room, **when three men break-in**, searching for a missing fortune.

IIRC, it unfolds as you described. It's dreary outside (Fincher, what else?) and the mother tries to tap into the house's phone at some point (theirs doesn't work) and also leaves their panic room to try and fetch her daughter's insulin kit. Here's the trailer:

Comment: Wikipedia link - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panic_Room